# No such a file or directory in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, directory, azure-functions, azureportal

I have create azure function. In that function I have different folders in which some files exists. After deployment to azure portal, I cannot see any folder/directory in that function. [image]

I am trying to write file in one of those folders. But when it try to write it, it throws exception "No such file or directory"
[image]

Here is my azure function structure:
[image]

When I try to access any of the folder like "./model_weights/teacher", it throws "No such file or directory" exception.

Here is the code:

[image]

How can i access any of the folder in azure function?

Comment: can you also share the code snippet that is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error traces to `/home/site/wwwroot/` directory, to fix this, you can access `root` directory using `abspath`:

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

You can refer to [How To Access Azure Functions wwwroot Folder](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-azure-functions-wwwroot-folder), [How to access file in root directory in function app](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/567#issuecomment-549595193)
 and [Get root directory of Azure Function App v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015150/get-root-directory-of-azure-function-app-v2)