Reading variables from app settings another time in Azure Function App
I have a function app, the app settings has several different PATs
One of the function is an HTTP trigger, the request body will contain a specific name
and that name should be used to retrieve the corresponding PAT from app settings
I have tried Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, this doesnt seem to read from app settings at all
I have tried
var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
var pat = configuration[$"{name}_PAT"];


this was a struggle because the {name} is only available after the POST request comes in, and configuration read the app settings in startup.cs, which is before the function getting triggered
I also cant use configuration after the request had come in because of the {name} and public abstract void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) from FunctionsStartup doesn't have any forms that would take a string that's needed for the {name}

configuration read the app settings in startup.cs, which is before the function getting triggered - maybe try converting a section from appsettings.json into a Dictionary? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673985/558486.

does this only work with appsettings.json? because the app settings I have all the PATs in is on portal. Creating a dictionary on the portal is the double underscore right? I assume it'd look like PAT__companyA, PAT__companyB, PAT__companyC. If i do a var pat = configuration["PAT"], would it retrieve all three of them?

If I remember correctly, yes you're correct. For example, if there is a PAT section like "PAT": { "Foo": "xxx", "Bar": "yyy" } then yes, you can access its values using environment variables PAT__Foo and PAT_Bar. Using this solution you should be able to create a dictionary for section PAT.

You can still declare that section in the app settings file, with empty or dummy values. Values defined in the portal will override them, if you don't make any mistake :-)

Another workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476230/558486


I am using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable to access {name}_PAT values from Function App's App settings.
Primarily, I added 2 variables as shown below in App settings.



Then I am using given code to fetch the value.

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _78736864
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            
            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            string name =  data?.name;

            string patKey = $"{name}_PAT";
            string pat = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(patKey);

            return new OkObjectResult(new { PAT = pat });
        }
    }
}


I am able to get the expected values upon function invocation.





@nevermonday check the given solution. Hope this works for you?
